# Cannot manage SQL Server Express 2014 with SQL Server Management Studio 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014-express

A client has upgraded a database from SQL Server Express 2008 to SQL Server Express 2014.

I have lost the ability to edit data, or open tables in design mode for the 2014 database. I can still write stored procedures to do these tasks.

I was successfully using SQL Server Management Studio 2012 to edit data and make changes to the SQL Server Express 2008 database, and still can to an archived copy.

Can anyone advise if SQL Server Management Studio 2012 can be used to edit data and make changes to an SQL Server Express 2014 database?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general server/database  tech support/

Comment: In less words than you used to tell me of my error, you could have posted the correct link.  I am new here and do not know your cryptic rules.

Comment: Here's [what is on topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Per that page, http://superuser.com is a better fit for this type of question.

Comment: Perhaps you should restate your question. Should your last line be 2014 rather than 2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes.

However in case you want to work with this new database you have on a sql server express 2014, i suggest installing sql server management studio 2014.